# Defining a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: triangles, transformation, coordinate-systems

I was trying to do this exercise but my answer doesn't match with the solution and I'm wondering why:

> Consider the coordinates transformation defined by $x=2u+v$ and $y=u^2-v$. Being $T$ the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,2)$ on plan $uv$ determine the image of $T$ on plan $xy$ by the coordinates transformation.

So what I did was take the vertices and apply the the transformation obtaining $(0,0)$ $(2,1)$ and $(2,-2)$.

Then I represented then in the plane $xy$ and I formed the triangle.

Then I defined my conditions:

- $0<x<2$
- $-x<y<\frac{x}{2}$

However the solutions say the proper answer for $y$ would be:

- $-x<y<\frac{x^2}{4}$

And I wonder why since it's supposed to be a triangle. So is it possible to be limited by a parabola?

Answer (score 1):

You found the images of the vertices of the given triangle. But the images of the straight lines making up the sides of the given triangle are *not* mapped to *straight* lines.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Can you explain me why and how do I obtain the sides of the triangle please?